# How to downgrade TexPad to version 1.4.7?

Tags: macbook-pro, mac, mac-appstore, downgrade, latex

This morning I made the worst mistake ever: I upgraded TexPad app (LaTeX App) to the newest version (1.8.something).

I need to downgrade to 1.4.7 for it was the best stable and fluid latex app ever.

Is there a way? I really need it.

Comment: Where did you install it from? Can’t you just restore it from your backup?

Comment: @nohillside The very first time I got it it was from the apple store on Mac, in 2014. Yet I have no backup available. I have managed to find older version on the website so far, and I got the version 1.6.something. It works rather fine (some crash here and there).